# Lost everything after using install-mbr

Tags: linux, bios, mbr

I was dual booting Windows 8 and BackTrack5 but I erased the MBR while using easyBCD. So I tried this…

```
sudo install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sda1
```

`/dev/sda1` was the primary partition in my system which is "System Reserved" for Windows.
When I rebooted my system, it got stuck at the boot logo "HP" and BIOS won't show up even when I pressed the <kbd>Esc</kbd> to pause start up.
I tried to boot BackTrack5 linux from flash drive, but the flash drive won't get detected, since BIOS itself is not showing up!
My BIOS version is "Insyde F.66A" and I am using HP pavilion dv4t-1300 CTO notebook PC.

What could be the reason for BIOS not showing up? Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed up `sda` and `sda1`. It usually does not make sense to install an MBR into a partition instead of the drive itself. You would have needed this command:

```
sudo install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sda
```

Unfortunately your mistake may have destroyed important file system data in `sda1`. With Linux file systems the first sector of a volume is left alone so that boot code can be installed there. If the Windows file system does the same then you are lucky and just have to reinstall the boot loader under Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You modified the partition `/dev/sda1`, which contains parts of the UEFI BIOS. This makes your system unbootable.

You should be able to recover by [reflashing the BIOS](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00042629&tmp_track_link=ot_faqs/top_issues/en_us/c00042629/loc:4&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&os=2093&product=3884600&softwareitem=ob-69653-1). Obtain the [appropriate BIOS image](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4062&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3884600#N1267). You get a self-extractible archive, which you can unpack with `7z x sp48847.exe` or `cabextract sp48847.exe` under Linux. You get a file `Winflash.exe` in turn is a zip archive which you can unpack with `unzip Winflash.exe` or `7z x Winflash.exe`.

At this point, if you can figure out which `*.FD` file contains the right BIOS version and you can find the signature file, you can [write them at the appropriate location on a USB stick](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/35272-HP-Insyde-BIOS-recovery-steps), and boot your PC with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> pressed.

Alternatively, mount the notebook's drive in another PC and find out which `*.FD` file corresponds to your BIOS. if your notebook's drive is `/dev/sdn`:

```
</dev/sdn1 tail -c +513 | head -c 1000000 md5sum
for x in *.FD; do tail -c +513 $x | head -c 1000000 | md5sum; done
```

If you have a match, overwrite the first 512 bytes back from the clean image.

```
dd bs=512 count=1 <xxxxxxxx.FD >/dev/sdn1
```

Next time, remember to install the MBR on `/dev/sda`, not `/dev/sda1`. Don't touch anything on `/dev/sda1`.